# What is the deference between lda[doc_bow] and lda.inference(corpus)?

Tags: python, lda, gensim

In the LDA model these are the two methods to inference the new documents using existing model i think. what are the differences between these two methods ?

Comment: Without looking at the documentation, the argument name suggests that `lda[doc_bow]` expects a preprocessed "bag of words" as input.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some tests where my ldamodel has 8 topics, and here my results:
2 docs to predict topic:

```
list_unseenTw=[['hope', 'miley', 'blow', 'peopl', 'mind', 'tonight', 'gain', 'million', 'fan'],['@mileycyrustour', "we'r", 'think', "it'", 'pretti', 'cool', 'miley', 'saturday', 'night', 'live', 'tonight', '#prettycool']]
```

1. Prediction with lda[doc_bow] (it gives already a percentage of matching topic)

   doc_bow = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in list_unseenTw]
   predictions = ldamodel[doc_bow]

   predictions[0]:
   [(0, 0.02509002728802024),
    (1, 0.0250114373070437),
    (2, 0.025040162139306051),
    (3, 0.82462688228515812),
    (4, 0.025150924341817767),
    (5, 0.025000027675139792),
    (6, 0.025000024127660267),
    (7, 0.025080514835853926)]

   predictions[1]:
   [(0, 0.031250011319462589),
    (1, 0.031250013721820222),
    (2, 0.031250019639505598),
    (3, 0.031250015093378707),
    (4, 0.031250019670816337),
    (5, 0.031250024860739675),
    (6, 0.78124988084026048),
    (7, 0.031250014854016454)]
2. Prediction with ldamodel.inference (the results are given in a weight not percentage)

   pred= ldamodel.inference(doc_bow)

   print(pred)

   (array([[ 0.12545023,  0.1250572 ,  0.12520085,  4.12309694,  0.12579184, 0.12500014,  0.12500012,  0.12540268],
           [ 0.12500005,  0.12500005,  0.12500008,  0.12500006,  0.12500008, 0.1250001 ,  3.12499952,  0.12500006]]), None)

As you see the result for the first prediction (doc1) is the same (topic 3) as you do:

```
total=0

for i in pred[0][0]:

        total+=i

4.12309694/total = 0.82462%
```